# Get current URL of browser

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In Selenium Nodejs, How can I get the current url of the page I'm testing (the moment my test script is running assume that the page initially has been redirected)

Comment: I found this link, might be helpful:  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/url

Comment: Is standard method not working here? http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getCurrentUrl()

Comment: I'm working with nodeJS

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    .then(function() {
        return driver.getCurrentUrl();
    })
    .then(function(currentUrl) {
        // work with the current url of browser
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(api.driver.getCurrentUrl().toString())
```

Answer (score -1):

To show you must to use toString:

```
var currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl().toString();
console.log("***>>> getCurrentUrl: "+currentURL);
```

Comment: Actually when i use your code i am getting
ManagedPromise::1143 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}